# How does ReCAPTCHA work?

Tags: security, captcha, recaptcha, spam-prevention

My reading of this [article](http://www.google.com/hostednews/ap/article/ALeqM5g8aqRqCZGTwZZFcQUwKoK8zM3VPQD9AOJ9BO0) suggests that a benefit of ReCAPTCHA is that it can have humans verify words not recognised in the OCR/digitization of books. It does this by using these words in "Are you human?" tests. So ReCAPTCHA kills two birds with one stone. Great!

But I dont get it. If the word can't be recognised by the digitization process then what is the input entered, by the supposed human being, verified against? How does this work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It shows two words.  One of them the computer already knows, the other, it doesn't.  It assumes that if you get the known one right, that you must know the other.

You don't know which of the two is already known so you, theoretically can't trick it.  Additionally, it will replay a word with multiple people to get independent confirmation before sending it back to the source (newspaper company, book scanning group) as a valid answer.

> But if a computer can't read such a
>   CAPTCHA, how does the system know the
>   correct answer to the puzzle? Here's
>   how: Each new word that cannot be read
>   correctly by OCR is given to a user in
>   conjunction with another word for
>   which the answer is already known. The
>   user is then asked to read both words.
>   If they solve the one for which the
>   answer is known, the system assumes
>   their answer is correct for the new
>   one. The system then gives the new
>   image to a number of other people to
>   determine, with higher confidence,
>   whether the original answer was
>   correct.

http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html

Comment: I would note that ReCAPTCHA works by showing two words, one which it knows and another it doesn't.  You just need to get one correct.  However, they resubmit the one that they don't several times until they get a high percentage that it is correct before they absorb it as such.

Comment: Good point, the system isn't fool proof, though it is clever.  It reminds me of Google's Image Labeler game which works by the same principles to get unknown people to label images: http://images.google.com/imagelabeler/

Comment: Imagelabeler and ReCapcha are by the same guy: Luis von Ahn.  He really led the way on using humans to solve hard problems.

Comment: Ok great and thanks for the link. So the image kinda picks up a "reputation" for being a given word as "voted" on by numerous people in the human verification process. Just out of interest, any idea how many "votes" an images must get before it is accepted or retired?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but the work "reputation" is a good one.  It fits well with the "knowledge of crowds" concept.

Comment: According to wikipedia reCaptha has stopped using control words as of September 2014. This answer needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from [LEARN HOW reCAPTCHA WORKS](http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html)

> But if a computer can't read such a CAPTCHA, how does the system know the correct answer to the puzzle? Here's how: Each new word that cannot be read correctly by OCR is given to a user in conjunction with another word for which the answer is already known. The user is then asked to read both words. If they solve the one for which the answer is known, the system assumes their answer is correct for the new one. The system then gives the new image to a number of other people to determine, with higher confidence, whether the original answer was correct.